# IcCube - How can I Make The Histogram (AMCHARTS/ Serial) Hidden

Tags: iccube

my report contain a PieChar and a Histogram , at first i'm need that just The PieChart is shown and the Histogram is hidden, what i'm need is when I click on the pieChart the Histogram must be shown.

I change Behavior-> "Pop-up" but it's still shown

I try to apply this demo [Demo](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html?ic3reportName=Box%20Behaviour) but the histogram still shown, i don't know why??

Any one can help me on that ???. THX,B.Marwen

Answer (score 0):

Behavior -> "Pop-up" won't be applied in Editing mode. It works only in reporting mode.

You have to tie them to each other with event (e.g. set "onCellClick" event value in Pie Chart and filter by this value in histogram).

Comment: Yes of Course , there is a event between the Pie Chart and the histogram, reely i found a problem in this point because in the demo it run correctly and i apply it but without a result, i need help to resolve this

Comment: By apply the demo, it's the same result, at the first loading the histogram is shown and the behavior is "Pop Up" and there is an event between it and the PieChart, it's really weird.